# A question about dipole approximation

Tags: electrons, schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, quantum-optics, dipole

While reading Chapter 5 in [1], I became confused with the dipole approximation and the $\bf{r}\cdot \bf{E}$ Hamiltonian. The total Hamiltonian is given by $H=H_0+H_1$, where $H_1=-e\bf{r}\cdot\bf{E}(\bf{r}_0,0)$. When considering this Hamiltonian to describe an electron, should $e$ take the value of $1$ or $-1$ in natural units? Additionally, does the Hamiltonian take the form $H=H_0+\bf{r}\cdot\bf{E}(\bf{r}_0,0)$ or $H=H_0-\bf{r}\cdot\bf{E}(\bf{r}_0,0)$?

[1] Scully, Marlan O., and M. Suhail Zubairy. "Quantum optics." (1999): 648-648.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$H_1$ is just the interaction Hamiltonian $-\vec p.\vec E$ of the dipole $\vec p$ formed by the electron at point $\vec r_0$ in your notation and the proton at the origin with the electric field. The dipolar moment is therefore $\vec p=-|e|\vec r_0$ so the Hamiltonian is
$$H_1=|e|\vec r.\vec E$$

Comment: Thank you.  The proton is  at the origin.